# Memory leak when retrieving data from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsfetchrequest

Hey, I've created a custom retrieval method for database access:

```
+(NSArray*) recordsForTable:(NSString *)table predicate:(NSPredicate *)prd{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:table inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:prd];

    NSArray *records = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    [fetchRequest release];

    return records;
}
```

i then use the above method in this method:

```
-(NSArray *)tableViewControllerData{

    NSNumber *savedBool = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:YES];

    NSString *onlyGetSavedVisitObjects = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bolSaved=%@", savedBool];
    [savedBool release];
    NSMutableArray *data = [[[CoreDataAccess recordsForTable:@"LPVisit" stringPredicate:onlyGetSavedVisitObjects] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dteVisitDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateDescriptor, nil];
    [data sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

    return data;    
}
```

The trouble am having is that when the user makes changes to the LPVisit table and recall this method to show those changes it crashes the application.

[EDIT]

The exception it produces is:

```
 -[__NSArrayM objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4dac1f0
```

I believe the error is at line:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[[CoreDataAccess recordsForTable:@"LPVisit" stringPredicate:onlyGetSavedVisitObjects] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

If I remove the autorelease, I get a memory leak but the application doesn't crash.

Does anyone have any insights, thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason why you're not use the NSFetchedResultsController. You can handle any update/delete/insert into the table directly form the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

Comment: @rckoenes Its an existing application (that I didn't create) and I was hoping to just drip into the code and add the edit functionality that the above method helps with

Comment: Do you have any crash message for us, that will give us a bit more to go on.

Comment: @rckoenes sorry about. I've updated the original post to include the error message and line where I think it occurs

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the mutable copying is throwing the exception because `*records` is `nil`? This might happen if `@"bolSaved=%@"` is a typo and should be `@"boolSaved=%@"`.

Comment: thanks for response. Sadly not a typo, just checked to see if records is nil but its not

Comment: Oh well :) If you step through that code with a debugger, is everything the type you expect to be? No unexpected nils? What line does it throw the exception on?

Comment: when I step through the code it goes off somewhere I can't follow and its there that it crashes. Think am going to have to re-implement it as a fetchrequestcontroller but would still really like to now what is causing it for future

Comment: What is the last line of your own code it hits before you can't follow it anymore and it crashes?

Comment: it finishes creating the all the table cells